# Why does this javascript code using prototype work?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this javascript code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <script>
            function Person(first, last) {
                this.first = first;
                this.last  = last;
            }

           Person.prototype.toString = function() { 
                return this.first + this.last;
           }
            var person = new Person("John", "Dough");

            alert(person); // same result since alert calls toString()  

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The question is why does the `alert(person)` display "JohnDough"? To me, `alert(person)`  should not display anything.

Comment: Doesn't the comment in your code answer your question?

Comment: `alert` calls `toString()` of the passed object, just like the comment says: *alert calls toString()*. And `toString` is overwritten on the prototype to concatenate the first and last name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `alert`, the method implicitly attempts to call a `toString` on the object. In your case, `toString` is defined and does what you expect when explicitly calling `toString`. If you hadn't defined `toString`, `alert` would have used the native `toString` method of an `Object` and returned "[object Object]", as pointed out by @FelixKling.

Comment: The default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`. That's what you would see. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BN8L7/.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes yes, thank you. Don't know why I didn't think of that, or tried it in a fiddle or something

Comment: Ok Ian I think I get it. if I remove the toString method then the alert function alerts object Object . If I change the method to toString1 the alert uses object Object again. Only because toString was defined the alert replied JohnDough and only for that reason ?

Comment: @jimdif Yeah, simply because you defined it, it basically "overrides" the native implementation of returning "[object Object]"

Answer (score 1):

It's because that object has a toString() method. alert() requires a string, and will use this method for an object if it exists, or its own built-in one if not. As the method here returns the forename and surname, that's what you get in the alert() dialogue.

Comment: Ashley I am not sure if what you are saying is correct. The name JohnDough will not be alerted if the toString method does not exist via the prototype declaration. If it does not then object Object is alerted and not JohnDough .