# Why do the document.write() and alert() methds render JavaScript objects differently?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `document.write()` method and `window.alert()` when printing arrays and objects?

The different behaviors are shown in this code sample:

```
var arr = new Array("Maizere","Pathak");

document.write(arr); // output: Maizere,Pathak
alert(arr); // output: maizere,pathak
```

Why are they both printing the values? Shouldn't `alert()` print `Object Object`?

With a DOM object, it prints [object HTML collection] and here it is printing values.

Comment: alert(arr) it works fine

Comment: Both seems to have same result, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/NFpRh/

Comment: The `"[object Type]"` you mentioned is just the [default result of `toString()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2). Sub-types have the option to define their own `toString()` though. And `Array` [does just that](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2), defining that their *string representation* is equivalent to calling `join()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript have a `toString` method. This method is called whenever the object is used in a way that text is expected. For instance, the following outputs `[object Object]`:

```
alert({});
```

Arrays have their own version of the `toString` method that does something altogether different. Rather than showing their type, they show their contents, joined by commas. You can replace an arrays `toString` method if you like:

```
var names = ['Jonathan', 'Sampson'];

names.toString = function () {
    return this.length;
};

alert(names); // Outputs 2
```

You can use something else's `toString` implementation too if you like:

```
document.toString.call(names); // [object Array]
```

For additional information, see [`toString` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/k6xhc6yc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: what are the  conditions/environment needed for type coersion to takes place?

Comment: @Maizere When it's used where text is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Both `alert` and `document.write` are setup to work with the `.toString()` method.  For instances of type `object`, this usually prints `[object Object]`.  However, the Array class has overloaded this method to print the contents of the array.  Try doing `arr.toString()` to show this is the case.  If you create an object and give it a toString method, it will be called for alert.  For example:

```
var obj = {};
obj.toString = function() { return "I'm an Object!"; }
alert(obj);
```

will show an alert with the string "I'm an Object!" in it.

Comment: can u give me a reference to this post

Comment: The first one I found was actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340549/why-does-this-javascript-code-using-prototype-work but http://freewebdesigntutorials.com/javaScriptTutorials/jsArrayObject/toStringMethod.htm also talks about it.

Answer (score 1):

Both the document.write and window.alert methods use a string, so the Array.toString method will be used to produce a string value from the array.

What the toString method produces from different types of objects may vary between browsers, but you will get the same result from document.write and window.alert as they use the same method to produce the string.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Jonathan Sampson's answer and to give a little mind crusher...

```
var names = ['Jonathan', 'Sampson'];
names.toString = function () {return 0;};
names.valueOf = function () {return 1;};

console.log(names + ""); // 1 or 0 ? What do you think.
console.log(names.toString()); // 1 or 0 ? What do you think.¨
alert( names );
```

[See demo](http://jsbin.com/ojozus/1/embed?javascript,console)